# Count number of rows (including empty rows) in an excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, interop

Using C#, which method would give me a row count of 8? 
Right now I am using
CurrSheet.Rows.CurrentRegion.EntireRow.Count
but it is only returning 2. So it is stopping on the first blank row.

This is the screenshot of  the spreadsheet and my question:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count;`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use Excel commands,use a Streamreader and read the file:

```
Streamreader sr=new StreamReader("yourfilepath")

using (sr)

{
    int i=0;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
      {
       sr.ReadLine();
       i++;
      }
}
```